# When Trying to Save an R object in a list of objects, R says the object is not found

Tags: r

I searched and could not find a suitable solution in the other questions.

I have a function where I am looping through a list of objects (object_list.)  Later in the function, I want to save each individual object of this list as an .Robj file. Here's the command I am using:

```
save(object_list[[i]], file = paste(sample_names[[i]], ".Robj",sep=""))
```

When I run the function, I get this error:

```
Error in save(object_list[[i]], file = paste(sample_names[[i]],  : 
object ‘object_list[[i]]’ not found
```

Any help would be great!

Edit:  Also, to clarify, the list of objects exists and I was able to reference the list many times beforehand in the script using object_list[[i]]

It's just saving each object of the list that is giving me issues.

Comment: It does. Ran that command in the function and received a TRUE output

Comment: you can do x= object_list[[i]]; save(x, file = paste(sample_names[[i]], ".Robj",sep=""))

Comment: Because I don't see how you can save one part of a list..

Comment: @StupidWolf - thanks!  This did the trick. I guess with the save command, it needs to know the exact element of the list that you want to save.